# How to set Time zone for Withschedule of quartz not with CronSchedule

Tags: c#, .net, quartz

This is my code below, Please dont post answers for WithCronScheduler as i know how to use with it, my use case is specific to below

```
        SimpleScheduleBuilder simpleScheduleBuilder = SimpleScheduleBuilder.Create()
          .WithInterval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(schedule.IntervalSchedule.Interval));

          ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
          .ForJob(jobDetail)
          .WithSchedule(simpleScheduleBuilder)//, tz => tz.InTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneId)))
          .WithIdentity(schedule.Id.ToString())
          .StartAt(startTimeUtc: schedule.IntervalSchedule.Start)
          .EndAt(schedule.IntervalSchedule.End)
          .Build();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in next manner:

```
ITrigger myTrigger= TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .StartNow()
                .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule(
                    s => s.WithIntervalInHours(1)
                        .StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(12, 30))
                        .InTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo.Utc))
                .Build();
```